# how to connect using python to mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, nameerror, connector

This might be a simple one, but I couldn't figure it out. I couldn't connect to the database that I created 'clearview' in mysql through.
Please advise. Thanks!

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3 try:
----> 4     connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
      5                                          database='clearview',

NameError: name 'mysql' is not defined

Comment: Did you forget the import statement? See [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the mysql-connector package? Try installing it first with `pip install mysql-connector` and then import the package `import mysql.connector` before running your script.

Comment: Yes, I re-install to all environment, but not sure if I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere on that same file there should be something like this at the top:

`import mysql.connector
...
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', 5 database='clearview', ...`

you should also have the python libraries for mysql installed on your machine.
see more -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html

Comment: I reinstall in every environment I created to make sure it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python you are using???
a)first check you have `import mysql.connector`. If it is there and not working then can follow following steps.

b) It may be that mysql is not properly installed .Check via `pip search mysql-connector | grep --color mysql-connector-python` .

c) Install via : `pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

All comments & suggestions appreciated. I did everything suggested here. And yes, I basically have to install the mysql.connector to every environment I created to be sure. I think perhaps, that's why it indicated that mysql is not defined. Lesson learned>..

As follow up question... is there such thing as installing every Python extensions globally so I would not reinstall it in several environments. never tried it before, as I perhaps tinkering with different environments not knowing which one I'm currently using. :)

Thanks guys!!!